# Hilbert's Basis Theorem by induction on maximal degree

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, commutative-algebra

Please help me check if the following proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem is correct.

Proposition: If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, then so is $A[X]$.

Proof: It suffices to show that every countably generated ideal is finitely generated. Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq A[X]$ be any sequence, and $I$ be the ideal they generate. First show that we can replace $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ by another sequence with bounded degree. Let $I_0\subseteq A$ be the ideal generated by the leading coefficients of $f_n$'s (which equals the set of leading coefficients of polynomials in $I$). There exists $N$ such that the leading coefficients of $f_1,...,f_N$ already generate $I_0$. Let $d=\max\{\deg f_n\mid 1\leq n\leq N\}$. If $i>N$ and $D=\deg f_i\geq d$, then by subtracting some $A$-combination of $x^{D-\deg f_1}f_1,...,x^{D-\deg f_N}f_N$ from $f_i$, we can replace $f_i$ by some $f_i'$ without changing $I$, and ensure that $\deg f_i'\leq d-1$.

Thus we may assume the sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded degree $d$. Next we show that finitely many of them already generate $I$, by induction on $d$. The case $d=0$ is just the fact that $A$ is Northerian. For general case, as in the previous paragraph we can choose an equivalent sequence such that $\deg f_i\leq d-1$ for all $i>N$ for some $N$, so $\langle f_{N+1},f_{N+2},...\rangle$ is finitely generated by induction hypothesis, whence $I=\langle f_1,f_2,...,f_N,f_{N+1},f_{N+2},...\rangle$ is also finitely generated.

This is quite similar to the first proof on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem), but IMO slightly more natural since it avoids "inductively let $f_n$ be of minimal degree such that..."; there are also proofs that involve double indices which I abhor. What is the "most natural" proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem? Also here is how I understand the theorem: usually if the ideal $I$ increases, the zero set $V(I)$ should shrink by at least "one dimension", which can happen only finitely many times. Of course there are examples like $(f^2)\subsetneq(f)$ and $V(f^2)=V(f)$, but this should not happen too often, hence the theorem. Is this understanding correct?